# How to make a reaction when a user shake's the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, motion

I'm creating an app where when the user shake's the iPhone an animation plays, I'm using this code:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
{
    animation...
}
```

The thing is the code above reacts as soon as the user shake's the iPhone, just once. I need the user to shake it for up and down, as if they were shaking a bottle, for a few seconds and then the animation plays, also whilst they shake a mp3 file must play and when the animation plays a sound must play, please help, I am a total beginner so explain answers, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `int numOfShakes;`  in your .h file and increment it everytime the user shakes their phone and once they reach a certain amount of shakes then call the animation code

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
            if (numOfShakes == 10) {
                //animate
                //Shook for a couple seconds
                numOfShakes = 0;
            } else {
                numOfShakes++;
                if (numOfShakes == 1) {
                //play some mp3
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I have done the above and when i try it in the simulated the animation and music start as soon as i shake it twice, I don't know what I have done wrong?

Comment: sure, it won't fit on here, I have it on paste bin here: http://pastebin.com/h6h8wfik

Comment: yes, when do you want the mp3 to play? while they are shaking, correct?

Comment: hey just an update its the sound thats the problem now, if i shake 10 times the animation plays, but every time I shake the music plays and restarts every time :)

Comment: do you want the music to play just once?

Comment: I want it to just play 1 time during the whole 10 shake's until the animation :)

Comment: haha done, just a quick question how would I change it so that if the user stops shaking the music stop, and if they start shaking again the music starts again?? :) thanks